# iso c90 forbids mixed declarations and code

Tags: c

This is my coding and I am getting the above error in the line where i declared int *intpointer. Please help me in solving this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int intarray[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("intarray[%d] has value: %d - and address @ %x\n", i,     intarray[i], &intarray[i]);

int *intpointer = &intarray[4];
printf("address: %x - has value %d\n", intpointer, *intpointer); 

intpointer--;
printf("address: %x - has value %d\n", intpointer, *intpointer); 

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place this declaration

```
int *intpointer = &intarray[4];
```

in the beginning of the function code block after the declaration of `intarray`.

As error message reports you compile your code as C90 code that requires that declarations would be before other statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this problem is solved in C99 where we can declare variables anywhere in between the code.

Comment: @user2720353 The error message points out that you compile your code as C90 code.

Comment: Yeah...I compiled on C90 and thats why it showed error. When i tried the suggestion u gave, it worked and then i understood. Thanks for your guidance.